# Determine the maximum possible value of $S$.

Tags: number-theory

Every positive integer is marked with a number from the set $\{ 0,1,2\}$, according to the following rule:
$$\text{if a positive integer }k\text{ is marked with }j,\text{ then the integer }k+j\text{ is marked with }0.$$Let $S$ denote the sum of marks of the first $2019$ positive integers. Determine the maximum possible value of $S$.

**Attemp:** We claim the answer is 2021. It can be achieved: 2200|210|210|...|210|22 where the number of 210 is 671. Let the number of 2, 1, 0 be respectively $x_1, x_2, x_3$. We know $x_1+x_2+x_3=2019$ and we want to prove $2x_1+x_2 \leq 2021$. Therefore it's sufficent to prove $x_1-x_3<=2$. Indeed, for every positive integer $j \in\ \{1,...,2017\}$ which is marked with a 2, the number j +2 is marked with a 0. This implies that the number of positive integers less than 2017 marked with 2 is less than or equal to $x_3$.The conclusion follows

Can anyone write a possible better or more formal solution than this?

Comment: I like your solution.